# JS (GoogleScript, HTML Service, webapp) - How to catch a value from an input with a dynamic for-loop?

Tags: dynamic, textbox

I'm working with googlescript, so I have a Code.gs and a index.html.
I created a script inside the html which creates multiple inputs with a for-loop and dynamic names (input0, input1, input2 etc.).

I want to catch the values of these inputs in Code.gs with another function based on a for-loop. But unfortunatly the code to catch a value doesn't allow dynamic variables. Here comes my code (I shortened it):

```
function processForm(myForm) {

  var anzahl = myForm.member;
  Logger.log("anzahl :"+ anzahl);
```

for (var i=0;i

```
var itext = i.toString(); 
Logger.log("itext :"+ itext);
//var dyninput = "input"+i;
//Logger.log("dyninput: "+ dyninput);
var input = myForm.input+itext ;
Logger.log("input :"+ input);
```

}

The logs look like this:

[16-09-16 21:33:45:999 CEST] anzahl :2

[16-09-16 21:33:46:069 CEST] itext :0

[16-09-16 21:33:46:070 CEST] input :undefined0

[16-09-16 21:33:46:158 CEST] itext :1

[16-09-16 21:33:46:159 CEST] input :undefined1

I also tried

```
var input = myForm.dyninput ;
var input = myForm.input+i;
var input = myForm.input(i); // (+i) / [i] / [+i]
```

nothing works! 
The textbox id and name is "input0".
If I write manually "var input =myForm.input0" it works. :/

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: missing line:  for (var i=0;i<anzahl;i++){

Comment: I solved it - 

I used: var elements = document.getElementsByName("schuelername")

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var input = elements[i].value;
    google.script.run.processForm2(input);

And catched this value in the gs.script by processForm2(input);